# PHP REGEX: Help needed with PREG_SPLIT() for zip code

Tags: php, regex, zipcode, preg-split

I have content like

> San Clemente, CA 92673

or

> Arlington, TX 76012-3693

And I need to split it into `CityAndState` and `Zip`.
Some

I'm trying:

```
$moreAddressInfo = preg_split('^[0-9.]{5,}^', $row2['cityAndZip'],null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

(also tried without the flag)
... the CityState portion is getting returned just fine, but the main Zip info is missing 
(for the above two examples, *$moreAddressInfo[1]* would equal **''** and **'-3693'**, respectively).

Any pointers ?

Comment: `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` is useless until you have a group in the pattern.

Comment: since REGEX still seems like some kind of voodoo-magic to me, I'll have to take your word for it ;) ... any pointers/suggestions?

Comment: Just tell in your own words what you want that line of code to do for you.

Comment: I'd suggest you use preg match to find the position of the zip code, then split on that position and trim off the spaces and comma.

Comment: I want to break "Arlington, TX 76012-3693" into two vars .. 1) "Arlington, TX" .. 2) "76012-3693"

Comment: Ahah !!! preg match THEN split .. perfect, thanks.

Comment: There is no need to split after you used `preg_match`. `preg_match` will return all intermediate results, anyway. Just put the parts you need to output inside brackets like `~^(.*?)\s([\d\-]+)$~` or something. `preg_split` is used to split a string by matching a separator. You instead don't want to find this separator, but find the actual data inside the string. Thats what's `preg_match` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$moreAddressInfo = preg_split('~\s+(?=[0-9]{5})~', $row2['cityAndZip']);
```

- `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters.
- `(?=[0-9]{5})` is a positive lookahead; it *asserts* that the next part of the string is five digits, but doesn't *consume* them.

So your delimiter is some whitespace that's followed by five digits.

Comment: AWESOME !!!!! Thanks for the explanation. Exactly the results I was aiming for. :-D